# Dispatch method in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I was basically building an authentication system with reactJS by going through some references online.

I got really confused by the code segment below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { registerUser } from "../../actions/authActions";
                  .
                  .
                  .
const newUser = {
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      password2: this.state.password2
    };
this.props.registerUser(newUser, this.props.history); 
  };
                  .
                  .
                  .
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { registerUser }
)(withRouter(Register));
```

So basically, `registerUser` is an action, but instead of invoking it through the `dispatch` method, it's accessed by `this.props`? Why is that?

Also, `registerUser` is passed as an argument to the `connect()` method, why?

Comment: There's a section on that form of `mapDispatchToProps` in the documentation: https://react-redux.js.org/7.1/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#providing-a-mapdispatchtoprops-parameter . "First, encapsulating the dispatch logic into function makes the implementation more declarative. Dispatching an action and letting the Redux store handle the data flow is how to implement the behavior, rather than what it does. (...) In addition, you also gain the ability to pass down the action dispatching functions to child ( likely unconnected ) components."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a common pattern with redux. `connect` takes two arguments. The first maps the state and the second maps the dispatch actions. By using connect to wrap your component, both state and actions will be available through the props to your component.

It's a bit easier to understand when you actually map the dispatch calls:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
   return {
     registerUser: (user) => dispatch(registerUser(user))
   }
};


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withRouter(Register));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called mapDispatch to props. You can pass it as 2nd argument to `connect` funtion.

`mapDispatchToProps` is called with `dispatch` function as an argument

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
   return {
     registerUser: (user) => dispatch(registerUser(user))
   }
};
```

and then pass it to `connect` function as 2nd argument

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withRouter(Register));
```

The above can be simplified, by using a shorthand (Recommended by react-redux library)

**Shorthand**

Shorthand is by simply passing the actions in an object (in this case the registerUser)

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { registerUser }
)(withRouter(Register));
```

For more info https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch